# Why does hashCode() give the same result when called via "super" and "this"?

Tags: java, constructor, this, super

I know that super is a reference variable which is used to refer immediate parent class object. But I find the hashcode of both `super` and `this` are same which means they refer to child object.

Then, how is `super` used to invoke parent class object?

Sample code:

```
class Animal{
    int a;
    Animal(){
        System.out.println("animal constructor ");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    int b;
    Dog(){
        System.out.println("dog constructyor ");
        System.out.println(this.hashCode()+" "+super.hashCode());
        System.out.println(this.getClass()+" "+super.getClass());
    }
}
public class Super1{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Dog d=new Dog();
        System.out.println(d);


    }
}
```

Also classes of both the super and this are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that super is a reference variable which is used to refer immediate parent class object.

No it isn't. It is used to reference parent class *members*. There is no such thing as the 'parent class object'.

> But I find the hashcode of both super and this are same which means they refer to child object.

No it doesn't.

As you haven't overridden `hashCode()` in either of those classes, when you call it you will always get the same result, no matter which reference you call it with.

And the class of the object doesn't magically change when you call `super.getClass()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply....I read about super at this site [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/super-keyword) @EJP

Comment: That link is the usual Grade A drivel. Don't use third-party sites when there is a large Oracle site, full of matter.

Answer (score 1):

> which means they refer to child object than how "super" is used to
>   invoke parent class object

and

> Also classes of both the super and this are same.

I think that you don't get how the inheritancy works.
When you instantiate a subclass, it relies on the super class to create it (`super()`) but it doesn't create two objects.
Only an instance of the subclass is created.
Whereas the results that you get in your output.

As a side note, if you had overriden `hashCode()` in the subclass, invoking
 `super.hashCode()` and `hashCode()` could return a distinct result as the first one would invoke the parent method and the second one would invoke the overriden one.